# Como montar um ng-repeat usando "track by"?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="exibeUnidades">
        <table width="400">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100"><b>Profissionais</b></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by name">
                    <td width="100"><a href="#agendaProfissional/{{pro.idprofissional}}">{{pro.nome}}</a></td>
                    <td width="160">{{pro.funcao}}</td>
                    <td width="160">{{pro.unidade}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pois estou fazendo a seguinte consulta no banco:

```
<?php
$idestabel = $_GET['idestabel'];

    $getPro=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM unidade INNER JOIN profissional 
                          ON profissional.idunidade = unidade.idunidade WHERE idestabelecimento=:idestabel");
    $getPro=bindValue(":idestabel", $idestabel);
    $getPro->execute();

    while ($linhaPro=$getPro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $idunidade = $linhaPro['idunidade'];
        $unidade = $linhaPro['unidade'];
        $idprofissional = $linhaPro['idprofissional'];
        $idunidade = $linhaPro['idunidade'];
        $nome = $linhaPro['nome'];
        $funcao = $linhaPro['funcao'];

        $return[] = array(
            'idprofissional'    => $idprofissional,
            'nome'  => $nome,
            'funcao'    => $funcao,
            'unidade'   => $unidade
        );


    }
?>
```

Meu controller:

```
app.controller("ProfissionaisCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location, $rootScope) {

$rootScope.idestabelecimento = localStorage.getItem('idestabelecimento');

var getPro = function(){
    var idestabel = $rootScope.idestabelecimento;
    var opcao = 3 // Buscar profissionais
    $http.get("http://reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/profissionais.php?opcao="+opcao+"&idestabel="+idestabel).success(function(response){
        $scope.profissionais = response;
    })
}

getPro();

}]);
```

Que me retornar isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa é a mensagem que aparece no console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

angular.js:12477 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: pro in profissionais track by name, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: b

Retorno do console.log(response) att:Sorack
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

> [ngRepeat - Erro - dupes](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)
>
> `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: {0}, Duplicate key: {1}, Duplicate value: {2}`
>
> Occurs if there are duplicate keys in an `ngRepeat` expression. Duplicate keys are banned because `AngularJS` uses keys to associate `DOM` nodes with items

Em tradução livre:

> `Duplicados na repetição não são permitidos. Use a expressão 'track by' para especificar chaves únicas. Repetidos: {0}, Chave duplicada: {1}, Valor Duplicado: {2}`
>
> Ocorre se houver chaves duplicadas na expressão `ngRepeat`. Chaves duplicadas são banidas porque o `AngularJS` usa as chaves para associar os nodes do `DOM` com os itens.

O seu atributo `name` não existe no objeto, portanto está indo repetidas vezes como `undefined`. Você não pode utilizar um atributo que possa ser repetido no `track by`. Você pode utilizar outro campo como abaixo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by pro.idprofissional">
```

Ou utilizar o `$index`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by $index">
```

Ou ainda, se garantir que o nome do profissional não irá se repetir:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by pro.nome">
```

Lembrando que o `track by` serve para melhorar a performance quanto a percorrer objetos no `DOM`.

Comment: Realmente, o atributo name não existe no objeto, e sim nome.
Já tentei usar "<tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by idprofissional">" e o erro persiste. Tentei, também, "<tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by $index">" o aviso de erro some, mas também não aparecem os dados na tela kkkk

Comment: @GustavoSevero em qual parte você atribui os valores na variável `profissionais`?

Comment: Atualizei o post. Está no controller a variável profissionais.

Comment: @GustavoSevero coloca um `console.log(response)` antes da atribuição e posta na pergunta também, por favor

Comment: Pronto, está aí.

Comment: @GustavoSevero tenta trocar a linha de atribuição por isso aqui pra ver se funcionar: `$scope.profissionais = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: @GustavoSevero mudei o exemplo do código. Estava faltando o `pro.`. Tenta da forma que está agora, fazendo o favor

Comment: Eu também já tinha tentado colocar "<tr ng-repeat="pro in profissionais track by pro.idprofissional">" e não adiantou nada kkkk

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63947/discussion-between-sorack-and-gustavosevero).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Sorack, mas eu já consegui resolver... Eu estava com alguns erros na api, php.